# Классификация временного ряда

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

Есть некоторые измерения величин (1-787) фрагментов (fragment) - временные ряды по каждому фрагменту, которые принадлежат к определенным классам (class).

**Требуется:**
**1)** присвоить фрагменты классам, используя методы машинлернинга/статистического анализа
**2)** определить вероятностную оценку класса, принадлежащего каждому фрагменту
**3)** составить список фрагментов, которые нельзя однозначно отнести к какому либо классу.

В файле присутствует таблица технических шумов при измерении по каждому фрагменту, в процентах.
Так же недостающие значения в наборе данных заменяются случайными числами от 1 до 10.

Текст задачи был на английском, но я вроде все так перевел.
До этого момента с временными рядами никогда не сталкивался, не знаю про основные подходы и инструменты (догадываюсь, что могут подойти все базовые питоновские библиотеки по анализу данных), то ли каким то образом кластеризацию провести, то ли функцию временного ряда аппроксимировать, то ли еще что-то требуется..

Вот кстати попытка кластеризовать данные
[image: Попытка кластеризации]

В общем, буду признателен за любую помощь в решении. Датасет прилагаю:

https://yadi.sk/i/30wmu0ZOIgKylQ

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, про них я слышал, пытаюсь разобраться с этой задачей в короткие сроки. Если напишете какой-то код, это будет супер замечательно

Comment: можете пояснить какой столбец является искомым - `Class` или `Fragment`? Иными словами - у вас задача кластеризации или классификации?

Comment: Class, я так понял, что нужно определить, правильно ли фрагменты соотносятся с классами. И показать это. Я думаю сейчас это сделать таким образом: исправить выбросы по каждому фрагменту, померив значения доверительными интервалами (все что заходит за них - выброс) относительно скользящего среднего, интерполировать пропущенные значения, а после чего померить косинусное/евклидово расстояние между векторами, и тем самым выделить в группы самые похожие между собой. Правильный ли это подход, как считаете? Но тогда непонятно, для чего требуется таблица шумов в данных...

Comment: Я думаю лучший критерий оценки правильности подхода - это тесты ;-)

Comment: Я сделал, как описал, но однозначно определить (уникально) фрагменты к разным кластерам по косинусному/евклидову расстоянию не выходит, очень много похожих по расстоянию между собой рядов.

Comment: @MaxU, можете подсказать какой-то возможный подход? Я перерыл тонну инфы, так и не могу сообразить что тут надо сделать, пытался сделать иерархическую кластеризацию, так же применив метод главных компонент для признаков 1-787 пытался обучиться на каком то одном классе и предсказывать вероятность принадлежности других фрагменов к нему, ничего не выходит. А модели ARIMA и пр. которые вы назвали используются же для прогноза временных рядов, как они могут тут помочь?

Comment: а что у вас получилось в результате попытки кластеризации? Вы пытались визуализировать кластеры?

Comment: График кластеризации привел в вопросе. А в результате классификации, алгоритм почти всем проставлял дичь в районе 0.9.

Comment: К классу A ['A1' 'A2' 'A3']
принадлежит AA1 с вероятностью 0.938
принадлежит AB1 с вероятностью 0.936
принадлежит AB2 с вероятностью 0.924
принадлежит AC1 с вероятностью 0.929
принадлежит AC2 с вероятностью 0.939
принадлежит B1 с вероятностью 0.938
принадлежит B2 с вероятностью 0.896
принадлежит C1 с вероятностью 0.952
принадлежит C2 с вероятностью 0.938
....
ну и дальше в таком духе, только заного переучиваясь в цикле

Comment: я так до конца и не понял что вам нужно сделать - разбить данные на кластеры, не учитывая `Class` и `Fragment` или угадать класс по значениям (задача классификации) и можно ли в этом случае использовать `Fragment`? У вас есть постановка задачи на английском? И было бы неплохо опубликовать ваши попытки решения, чтобы вопрос соответствовал правилам ресурса...

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то кластеризация временных рядов - это не совсем тривиальная задача. Она, действительно, лежит на пересечении теории временных рядов и теории кластеризации. Как ее можно решать не зная первого и скорее всего -  второго, ума не приложу.  Даже подходов к ее решению есть несколько и выбор конкретного из них требует весьма глубокого погружения в тему. 
Если вас это не страшит - попробуйте ознакомиться для начала обзорами по теме, и выбрать, что вам более подходит.:

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0306437915000733
https://habr.com/ru/post/334220/
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/282320972_A_study_on_time_series_clustering
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0031320305001305
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.258.9630&rep=rep1&type=pdf
https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/metod-klasternogo-analiza-raznotipnyh-vremennyh-ryadov

Готовых решений достаточно мало. Встречался мне пакет на R

https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v062i01

Для Python аналогов не встречал. Впрочем, поняв суть, скомпоновать нужную программу из готовых компонентов (из Scikit-Learn) особых сложностей вызвать не должно.

Comment: Было бы желание, главное!) спасибо , ознакомлюсь с ссылками. K-means, DBSCAN пользовался, представляю как работают.